# How to extract tuple into a function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++14, template-meta-programming

I'm working with C++ on Linux and I need to develop a common library to simplify the multi-threading development.

Well, I know that there are some mechanism of multi-threading in C++11, such as `std::async`, `std::future` etc. But I have to work with `pthread` because of some historical reason.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to make a very very simple template function, which is kind of like `std::future`. Here it is.

```
template<typename S>
struct signature;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct signature<R(*)(Args...)> {
    using return_type = R;
    using argument_type = std::tuple<R(*)(Args...), Args...>; // f, args...
};

template<typename F, typename... Args>
void func(F* f, Args&&... args) {
    typename signature<decltype(f)>::argument_type tp = std::make_tuple(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    pthread_t td;
    pthread_create(&td, nullptr, [](void *p){
            auto param = static_cast<typename signature<decltype(f)>::argument_type*>(p);
            std::get<0>(*param)(std::get<1>(*param)); // ???
            return (void*)nullptr;
            }, &tp);
}

void f(int a) {}
void f2(int a, int b) {}

int main() {
    func(f, 1);
    // func(f2, 2, 2); ERROR!

    return 0;
}
```

In a word, I try to wrap the parameters of the function into a tuple and pass the tuple into the third parameter of `pthread_create`, which is a labmda.

So in the piece of code, `std::get<0>(*param)` is the function, and the rest part of the tuple `*param` is the parameter list which should be passed to the function. But I don't know how to expand it. Obvisouly, `std::get<0>(*param)(std::get<1>(*param));` is not OK because it can only handle the function with one parameter. If I want to pass a function with two parameters, I will get an error.

So how to expand the tuple there?

BTW, please ignore other issues, such as why don't call `pthread_join`. I just remove them here to minimize my post.

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)? BTW, any reason why to use pthreads instead of C++ threads?

Comment: @Daniel Langr Or even C++20 `std::jthread` which joins in its destructor.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oh, you are right, I was looking for it. Why not use `std::thread`? lol, that's because in my project, I work with neither `std::thread` nor `pthread`, it's a `pthread`-like old stuff... I have no right to change this because of some historical reason... My company developed its own thread, which contained many metrics stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `std::apply` is suitable for your case.

```
pthread_create(
  &td, nullptr,
  [](void* p) {
    auto param = static_cast<typename signature<decltype(f)>::argument_type*>(p);
    std::apply([](auto& f, auto&&... args) { 
      f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); 
    }, *param);
    return (void*)nullptr;
  },
  &tp);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/avdo54E1s)

Comment: Thanks man. You are right, and since I work with C++14, now I'm looking for an implementation of `std::apply` with C++14... lol

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use C++17 (`std::apply()`), I suppose you have to add a level of indirection...

Your `func()` can call a `func2()`

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void func(F* f, Args&&... args) {
    func2(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{}, f,
          std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

that receive also a template sequence of indexes, so your lambda, now inside `func2()` (I've removed the pthread part... sorry) can be written as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename F, typename ... Args>
void func2 (std::index_sequence<Is...>, F * f, Args && ... args) {
    typename signature<decltype(f)>::argument_type tp = std::make_tuple(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    [](void *p){
      auto param = static_cast<typename signature<decltype(f)>::argument_type*>(p);
      std::get<0>(*param)(std::get<1u+Is>(*param)...);
      return (void*)nullptr; }(&tp);
}
```